# preg_replace multi item in one line

Tags: php, preg-replace, line

What i'm gonna do is:

```
$oneline="[a]http://first.com/hi_underscoredot.htm[/a] [a]http://secondinoneline.com/hi_.htm[/a]";

$changeToHTML=preg_replace("/\[a\](.*)\[\/a\]/","<a href='$1'>$1</a>",$oneline);
```

The output expected is

```
echo $changeToHTML;
OUTPUT >> http://first.com/hi_underscoredot.htm http://secondinoneline.com/hi_.htm
```

But the real output is (which is not as expected):

```
echo $changeToHTML;
OUTPUT >> http://first.com/hi_underscoredot.htm[/a][a]http://secondinoneline.com/hi_.htm
```

As you can see the very last output just above this text, you can see [/a][a] not replaced and the link is become as ONE LINK. I don't want that.

I want they seperated as TWO LINKS?

How?

Anybody can help me?

p/s: this is in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much more simple fix than those already given:

```
$changeToHTML=preg_replace("/\[a\](.*?)\[\/a\]/","<a href='$1'>$1</a>",$oneline);
```

Works fine.

The combination `*?` means: Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]. Also see [this](https://regex101.com) helpful site to check your regex online.

Comment: thanks....simple and works for me...
and can i know what is the symbol '?'  means?

Comment: *? means: Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]

Comment: it's the same switch as the one I introduced in my answer, except in this form it only applies the greediness inversion to the subpattern between parenthesis, whereas the U switch applies it to the whole pattern.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is `.*`, instead of it write something like `[^\[]*`

```
$changeToHTML=preg_replace("/\[a\]([^\[]*)\[\/a\]/","<a href='$1'>$1</a>",$oneline);
```

Comment: thanks....beside Calimero's answer, this answer also works for me...but i prefer Calimero's answer because it looks simple

Answer (score 1):

(.*) is currently matching as much as it can, which is its default behavior. You want it to match only until the delimiters are found, and nothing more. To that end, you can invert the greediness of the PCRE engine using the U modifier like so :

```
$changeToHTML=preg_replace("/\[a\](.*)\[\/a\]/U","<a href='$1'>$1</a>",$oneline);
```

see this page for more details : http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: the other answers are equally valid, however I made this one thinking you're not very experienced with regexps, and I know from experience a good regexp is one you can read & understand (i.e. not crippled by cryptic hieroglyphs). This solution does not alter the regexp itself, only the regexp engine behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yU2fS1/1)

```
(\[a\])([^\[]+)(\[\/a\])
```

with a replace pattern of

```
<a href='$2'>$2</a>
```

---

```php
$re = '/(\[a\])([^\[]+)(\[\/a\])/'; 
$str = "[a]http://first.com/hi_underscoredot.htm[/a] [a]http://secondinoneline.com/hi_.htm[/a]"; 
$subst = "<a href='$2'>$2</a>"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
/* Prints:
    <a href='http://first.com/hi_underscoredot.htm'>http://first.com/hi_underscoredot.htm</a> <a href='http://secondinoneline.com/hi_.htm'>http://secondinoneline.com/hi_.htm</a>
*/
```